# Trigger to update values

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, plsql

I want to create a trigger on my table Audit 
the function of trigger is :
it will set all values to NULL
which have string 'null'
means `'null' -> NULL`
how should i do it i want it for every column not any specific.

Comment: Instead of mopping the floor continuously, why not fix the leak? Why not get the user/application to insert genuine `NULL`s?

Comment: its is through webservice so i wan't it from my end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reflection in PL/SQL so you'll need to do it like this:

```
create or replace trigger aud_upd_biur
before insert or update on your_audit_table
for each row
begin
     if :new.col1 = 'null'
     then
         :new.col1 := null;
     end if;
     if :new.col2 = 'null'
     then
         :new.col2 := null;
     end if;
     ....
     if :new.col99 = 'null'
     then
         :new.col99 := null;
     end if;
end;
```

So, if your audit table has only a few columns cut'n'paste will suffice.  Otherwise you can generate the code out of the data dictionary.